# Reverse engineering the checksum algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, activex, reverse-engineering, checksum

I have an IP camera that receives commands using POST HTTP requests(for example to call PTZ commands or set various camera settings). The standard way of controlling it is through it's own web interface which is partially an ActiveX plugin and partially standard html+js. Of course because of the  ActiveX part it only works in IE under Windows.

I'm attempting to change that by figuring out all the commands and writing a small python or javascript code to do the same, so that it is more cross platform.

I have one major problem. Each POST request contains a calculated "cc" field which I assume is a checksum. The JS code in the cam interface points out that it is calculated by calling a function inside the plugin:

```
tt = new Date().Format("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
jo_header["tt"] = tt;

if (getCpPlugin() != null && getCpPlugin().valid) {
    jo_header["cc"] = getCpPlugin().nsstpGetCC(tt, session_id);
}
```

**nsstpGetCC** function obviously calculates the checksum from two parameters the **timestamp** and **session_id**. Real example(captured with Wireshark):

```
tt = "20171018231918"
session_id = "30303532646561302D623434612D3131"
cc = "849e586524385e1071caa4023a3df75401e5bb82"
```

Checksum seems to be 160bit. I tried both **sha-1** and **ripemd-160** and all combinations of concatenating tt and session_id I could think of. But I can't seem to get the same hash as the one the original plugin gets. The plugin dll seems to be written in c++. And I have almost no experience with decompilation to dive into this problem from that angle.

So my question basically is can someone figure out how they calculated that **cc**, or at least give me an idea in which direction to research further. Maybe I'm looking at wrong hash algorithms or something... Or give me some idea how I could somehow figure out what the original ActiveX function nsstpGetCC is doing for example by decompilation or maybe by monitoring it's operation in memory while running. What tools should I use?

Comment: Do you know which binary/executable is being called? This is a **big** topic, which can take days or weeks. I suggest you take a look at OllyDBG since this is windows. Assuming the code is running on windows.

Comment: I'd use email and contact the camera manufacturers.

Comment: No source code. No documentation. Only windows binary. The plugin in question is this one: https://codeload.github.com/GitHub-Z/plugin/zip/master   Honestly I'm not sure either if SO is the right place. I'm open for suggestions and if it is not appropriate - Big apologies to everyone!! It should be deleted then!

Comment: @UKMonkey, tried that... No response unfortunately :(

Comment: `nsstpGetCC` may be receiving only two parameters from JS, but that doesn't mean it doesn't use additional ones, like a secret salt.. The best way to proceed is probably by peeking at the source.

Comment: If you pass in the same data, do you always get the same result?

Comment: @Lou Franco, yes! So that example, always gives the same results... the same combination of tt and session_id gives the same cc

Comment: Maybe it is not a cc but encrypted data. Data seems decimal, except char D which can be separator. And date is quite restricted decimal data. If that is a case than input has much less bit of information than result.

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/